# Customer session being lost upon redirect from Payflow

Tags: php, payflowpro

I am totally stumped! We have customers who incur multiple charges and never have their orders completed. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to the cause. There is no consistent pattern. In fact, we just had a customer who was logged out (and charged). The customer immediately logged back in, and the order was successful (charged again). We have determined that the session of affected customers seems to be newly established upon redirect from Payflow. We cannot figure out the cause. I cannot reproduce this in development, no matter how many times I've tried. We are using the silent post method. Our sites run HTTPS-only, so there's no mixed protocol. Also ensured there is no mixed domain between `www` and `non-www`. I am at a complete loss. Any and all assistance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide code snippets otherwise it is pretty hard to guess what is going on in your application. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to begin with that. There's not a simple snippet to provide. The credit card data is posted directly to Payflow with a form. This is after obtaining a secure token by passing a token id along with the order details. It's just totally baffling, because I can see the same customer return from Payflow with no customer id on the first attempt. They of course get redirected to the login page. They're not sure what happened, so they login again and place the order (not knowing they were charged first time). This time, their session is intact on return from Payflow.

Comment: There is not much to advise without code snippet. I would recommend creating a simple demo app that uses exactly that flow and check that's behavior.